# present or past tense when referring books

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

You should read the book and see what he ***means/meant*** by......

Question: Do we use present or past tense for a book? And does it matter if it's fictional books (Shakespeare) or fact (political/religion)

Comment: The example context is "pathological", because as well as presenting the "**backshift or not?**" issue for the *(still **current**)*  *meaning* of ***past*** utterances / text, it's introducing further "temporal distractions" encapsulated in the implied ***future** act of reading*. I don't think any useful syntactic principle can be extracted from such an "unusual" context.

Answer (score 1):

Either "means" or "meant" is acceptable.

If you were being really fussy, you might say

> You should read Keynes's book "The Theory of Money" and see what **it means**

The intended meaning of a book's text does not change over time, and so its intended meaning is now what it ever was. Or you might say

"You should read Keynes's book "The Theory of Money" and see what **he meant**

Obviously Keynes does not currently intend any meaning today: he is dead. Moreover, it is conceivable (indeed highly likely) that Keynes changed his mind after writing that book and did not even intend that meaning at times while he was alive but had finished that book.

But, as I said, this is being very careful in what you write. No one should fault you for using "it means" or "it meant."